# Minimal configuration for Apache reverse proxy in Docker container

Tags: node.js, apache, docker, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I am trying to setup a Ubuntu Docker container which runs a Node.js HTTP app on port 9000. To mimic the setup of the production environment, I would also like to run Apache as a simple reverse proxy server within the container that forwards to this app from, say, port 80 (which I expose to the big bad world).

I've been able to set up the Node.js app container fine and I can install and setup Apache within my `Dockerfile`; but I'm completely new to setting up a reverse proxy, so while Apache certainly starts, it doesn't proxy.

My `Dockerfile` looks something like:

```
# DOCKER-VERSION 1.3.0
FROM    ubuntu:12.04

# Install and set up Apache as a reverse proxy
RUN     apt-get -y install apache2 libapache2-mod-proxy-html
COPY    apache2.conf /etc/apache2/app.conf
RUN     cat /etc/apache2/app.conf >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN     service apache2 start

# Install and set up Node.js and bundle app
# ...This works...

EXPOSE  80
CMD     ["./start-app.sh"]
```

...where the `apache2.conf` I'm appending to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` is:

```
ServerName localhost

LoadModule proxy_module      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule headers_module    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule deflate_module    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_deflate.so

<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass        / http://localhost:9000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9000/
```

I am running this image using the following command:

```
docker run -p 80:80 -p 81:9000 -d IMAGE
```

What I'm expecting is that going to `http://$DOCKER_HOST` (i.e., the root) will be picked up by Apache and forwarded to `localhost:9000` (i.e., my app) in the container. (If I go to `http://$DOCKER_HOST:81`, I go straight to the app; just to prove that it's up and running. This works.) I suspect that the problem isn't at all to do with Docker, but the Apache configuration.

Comment: Are you using the apache reverse proxy for the sole purpose of exposing your web server on port 80 instead of 9000 or would it have another purpose?

Comment: Exactly. On the production machine, Apache is doing other, unrelated stuff; I'm just putting the reverse proxy layer in my container so it matches the setup in production.

Comment: Pls edit your question with the command are you using to run your docker container

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your Dockerfile, the [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#run) statements define commands that will be run by the docker daemon when building the docker image. Those commands won't be executed when you use the `docker run` command.

In your case you are trying to come up with a docker image that would start two processes:

- apache server
- nodejs server

But the `start-app.sh` script in `CMD     ["./start-app.sh"]` seems to only start the nodejs server.

You cannot have the `docker run` command start more that one process, but you can have it start a process that will start others. There are differents ways to achieve this, take a look at:

- [Using Supervisor](https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/)
- [Phusion baseimage](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker)

but more simply you could replace your `CMD` instruction with:

```
CMD     /bin/bash -c "service apache2 start; ./start-app.sh"
```

and remove the useless `RUN     service apache2 start` line.

In your container, Docker will start one process (`/bin/bash`) which in turn will start apache and then run `./start-app.sh`.

Comment: note: you could also add `service apache2 start` at the top of the `start-app.sh` script

Comment: That did the trick :) Thank you...particularly your first paragraph cleared everything up for me.

Comment: Wouldn't this require that I run my container with root in order `service apache2 start`? Is there a way to accomplish the task with a regular user?

Comment: @fy_iceworld I would advise running two containers anyway, one for Apache (from official docker image) and one for your app. You won't have the issue of running the container as root this way. Or use Traefik instead of Apache for the reverse proxy role

Comment: @Thomasleveil I see. thanks for the quick reply!